# making the most accurate data structure - mySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I am working in java and I need to make database for data.

I have entity called Folder which has fields:

- int id
- String name
- Folder folder

**What is the best way to represent folder's reference to itself (Folder folder) in database?**

```
create table e_folder(
f_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
f_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
# ?
PRIMARY KEY (f_id)
);
```

Comment: As per my understanding you want a datatype for `folder` ? like `VARCHAR` or `BLOB`?

Comment: yes, can I make field with type of int and mark it as a foreign key which references my primary key ?

Comment: It will depend on what you're going to store in that? Are you storing the `int` for folder value?

Comment: @Kaushik I thought maybe it's the best to have only folder's id in database with which I can later easily access to other object's information. I just don't know if it's the best way

Comment: If I would be doing that I'll keep folder Id in one column and folder path in another column, so while displaying the data it will be easy.